# a python svr (use flask) run as deamon create a subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, subprocess

I implemented a python server programe using flask, when receive a specific msg, server create a subprocess to implement a python script, like below:

`process = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/python3', '/home/test/proc_one.py'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

the subprocesss script like below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time

def do_logic():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_logic()
```

when i run server on terminal, everything is ok. but when i run server as a deamon
`nohup python3 svr.py 11111  &`
, the server can not create subprocess.No error infomation. I use `process.poll()` get returncode value is 0 which indicate the process is termiate successfully.

Thanks a lot.